# MacBook M1 network issues when activating WiFi and USB ethernet adapter at same time

Tags: macos, network, wifi, apple-silicon, ethernet

I have a new MacBook M1 and had never such issues with my old MacBook before.

- WiFi works perfectly if no other ethernet adapter is connected.
- USB ethernet works perfectly if WiFi is disabled and IPv6 local link is activated.

But when I turn on both at the same time, or when I set IPv6 to automatic mode, no packet goes through.
Even DHCP is not working properly, when WiFi was on before.

As soon as I disable one of ethernet or WiFi, Packets go through immediately. (ethernet needs to have IPv6 on link local or it will not work anyway)

I'm running macOS 12.3.1 and I'm using Apple USB-Ethernet-Adapter (worked on my old Mac like a charm) WiFi settings are also the same as before.
Network environment is a company.

Has anybody an idea what's wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Could it be that both the Wi-Fi and Ethernet adapter get an IP address in the same network range (for example, Wi-Fi gets 192.168.1.10 and Ethernet gets 192.168.1.13)? What do you mean by "even DHCP is not working properly"?

Comment: Hello, yes both IPs are in the same routed network, but different DHCP ranges. Its the same setup then before with my old Mac where it worked for years. By "even DHCP is not working properly" I mean, if wifi is on and ethernet is off and if I then connect ethernet, the ethernet gets a 169.254.x.x address. Packets (Ping) is still working at that time via wifi. If I disconnect wifi, the ethernet gets a proper IP via DHCP shortly after and ping is working again. If I connect wifi again, DHCP IP is kept, but Ping is not working since both are now "connected"

Comment: PS: Thanks for editing. Also I can say that the default priority order is set: 1. Apple-USB-Ethernet-Adapter, 2. Wi-Fi, 3. Thunderbolt Bridge

Comment: Thanks, can you give an example of the IP addresses Wi-Fi and Ethernet get when disconnecting the other port?

Comment: I can't give you the exact IP since it is not private range. But its a Class C network (/24).  Just tested as well: DHCP discovery is working for wifi when ethernet is connected and I put on wi-fi afterwards. But no packet goes through from then on, like explained.

Comment: I'm surprised, I wouldn't expect the DHCP pool to be a public address range. Anyway, It's difficult to troubleshoot the issue without having a more accurate description of how DHCP is set up or what other network configuration is in place (like 802.1X profiles). You write this happens in an enterprise network, you may want to contact IT support for help.

Comment: 192.168… is private network. The problem you have us a routing problem : how can the computer knows on which network it needs to go  as both network are in same apparent network. You may need to check you have to check that default routing is only valid on 1 of the 2 interfaces. (169.254… is usually kind of default address for not connected hardware)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just got a response from our IT. It is a Palo Alto Firewall problem which is also installed on my MacBook.